# troubleshooting scrollbar html

Tags: html, scrollbar, tumblr, tumblr-themes

Since I can't really figure out where the problem is the cite is [here](http://testingthemestoday.tumblr.com)
I'm sure most people know ctrl-u will allow you to see the coding.
The scroll bar should move the content in the box.
Any suggestions are helpful but please don't be rude
The scrollbar is transparent but it should wok like the one on [this page](http://fortifiableyouth.tumblr.com/)

Comment: I do not see any scroll bar on the web page as you indicated. please elaborate more and ask be more precise about your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I'm currently seeing - your problem is that you have two separate `<div id="entries">` divs. The second one (line 1060 of your compiled source, as I'm seeing it in Firefox) is blank - it contains an empty `<div id="post">` and nothing else.

id properties have to be unique - because this one is repeated, the style attributes aren't being applied to it correctly. Simply delete the second `<div id="entries">`, and your scrollbar will work.